# How to add Tamil word in textview in my Android app

Tags: java, android

How to add Tamil words in textview in my Android app.
Actually now I am using the words like kuladevivangal . instead of kuladevivangal I need to use ‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌குலதெய்வங்கள். Please help me to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add tamil font to your project font folder

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/****.ttf");  //your tamil font             
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    tv.setText("குலதெய்வங்கள்");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unicode text directly by setting `tv.setText(unicode_String)`

If you want to use custom fonts like `Bamini` please follow the below steps.

1. Create a `font` directory under `res` directory in your Android studio project.
2. Set the font family inside the XML layout as followed

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="jkpo" <!--bamini font keys for தமிழ் -->
        android:fontFamily="font_from_res" <!-- set your desire font-->
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

for loading the text programmatically use `textview.setText("jkpo")` or your unicode text like `textview.setText("தமிழ்")`.

Note: using Unicode text will not provide stylish font for your desire.

I hope it will help.